# Vala file binary to struct like used c fread

Tags: filestream, vala

I am trying to convert directly from a binary file into struct. I can do it on c, but I don't know how to do it at the vala. I put the C and Vala code examples below.

```cpp
struct Header
{
    char name[30]; // PK2 internal name
    uint32_t version; // version
    uint8_t encryption; // does have encryption?
    uint8_t verify[16]; // used to test the blowfish key
    uint8_t reserved[205]; // unused
};

read_count = fread(&m_header, 1, sizeof(Header), m_file);
    if(read_count != sizeof(Header))
    {
        fclose(m_file);
    }
```

I'm trying to do the same with the vala. But I never did.

```cs
struct Header
{
    char  Header[30];          //JoyMax File Manager!
    uint    Version;        //0x02000001
    uint8    Encrypted;
    uint8  Verify[16];          // Used to test the blowfish key
    uint8  reserved[205];        // Unused
}

void main()
{
    var file = FileStream.open ("file.bin","r+");

    char name[30] = {0};
    file.gets (name);
    print((string)name);
}
```

Is there a way to convert from file to struct directly like fread ?

Answer (score 1):

You can cast your struct to a `uint8[]` and then call `File.read` on it like this:

```
void main()
{
    var file = FileStream.open ("file.bin","r+");

    Header header = new Header ();
    file.read ((uint8[]) header);
    stdout.printf ((string) header.Header);                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

Disclaimer: This is obviously not very safe code and the `printf` will only work with a properly zero terminated `Header` member.